# Перегрузка операторов перечисляемого типа в Delphi

Tags: delphi, перегрузка-операторов, delphi-xe

Можно ли перегрузить оператор для перечисляемого типа?
т.е. имеем например:

```
Type
  TAngle = (a0, a90, a180, a270);

Var
  AngleA, AngleB, AngleC: TAngle;

AngleA := a90;
AngleB := a180;
AngleC := AngleA + AngleB; //a270
AngleC := a270 + AngleB;   //a90
AngleC := AngleB + a180;   //a0
```

По идее перегрузить бы оператор сложения, но это возможно только для записей, как я понимаю? Может можно запись через Implicit неявно приводить к этому перечисляемому типу? Но тогда это всё равно будет уже новый тип.

Вообще логика такая получается, пока сделал через функцию:

```
Result := TAngle((Ord(AngleA) + Ord(AngleB)) Mod 4)
```

Comment: Используйте общий тэг `delphi`, чтоб вопросы увидело больше людей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как уже сказано в ответе @zed перегрузка доступна только для записей. Поэтому, если хочется, вы можете добавить соответствующую структуру, и работать с ней.

```
TAngleValue = (av0, av90, av180, av270);

TAngle = record
    FValue : TAngleValue;

    function getAngle():integer;
  public
    class operator Add(a, b: TAngle ):TAngle;
    class operator Implicit(angle: TAngleValue):TAngle;

    property Angle: integer read getAngle;
    property Value: TAngleValue read FValue;
end;
```

перегрузив сложение и, для начала, неявное приведение

```
class operator TAngle.Add(a, b: TAngle): TAngle;
begin
    result.FValue := TAngleValue( (byte(a.FValue) + byte(b.FValue)) mod 4);
end;

class operator TAngle.Implicit(angle: TAngleValue): TAngle;
begin
    result.FValue := angle;
end;

function TAngle.getAngle(): integer;
begin
    result := byte(FValue)*90;
end;
```

в итоге само манипулироввание значениями получится таким, как вы хотели

```
var a, b, c : TAngle;
begin
    a := av90;
    b := av180;
    c := a + b + av90;

    writeln( a.Angle, ' ', b.Angle, ' ', c.Angle);
    readln;
end.
```

Comment: Ну да, я в общем так и представлял, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя такого сделать.

В десктопных версиях Delphi перегрузка операторов возможна **только** у записей: [Operator Overloading (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)).

Для мобильных версий (с ARC) перегрузка доступна так же и для классов: [Class Operators in Delphi](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/class_operators_delphi.html)